# AS3 FTP Socket fails on 3G network

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, ftp, 3g

I have an AS3 Script which connects to an FTP server and retrievs file/folder list.
The script works fine when the device is connected to internet via WIFI or LAN but it fails to login when it's connected via mobiles 3G

Here's my code :

```
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.errors.IOError;
//
var ftp_host:String="ftp.server.com";
var ftp_port:Number=21//or your ftp port;
var ftp_username:String="username";
var ftp_password:String="password";
var ftp_path:String="/";
var s,r;
var listOfFiles:Array;
//


readFromFTP()

function readFromFTP(e=null){
    s = new Socket(ftp_host,ftp_port);
    r = new Socket();
    listOfFiles=new Array();
    s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);
    s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onReturnData);
    s.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,onSecERR);
    r.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onServData);
    r.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onPasvConn);
    r.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onIOERR);
    r.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,onSecERR);

    loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, handleGlobalErrors);
}


function onReturnData(evt:ProgressEvent)
{
    var d = s.readUTFBytes(s.bytesAvailable);
    trace(d);
    text_txt.appendText(d);
    if(d.indexOf("220 ")>-1){
       text_txt.appendText("Username sent\n");
       s.writeUTFBytes("USER "+ftp_username+"\n");
       s.flush()
    }
    if(d.indexOf("331 ")>-1){
        text_txt.appendText("Password sent\n");
       s.writeUTFBytes("PASS "+ftp_password+"\n");
       s.flush()
    }
    if (d.indexOf("230") > -1)
    {
        text_txt.appendText("PASV command sent\n");
        s.writeUTFBytes("PASV \n");
        s.flush();
    }
    var a = d.indexOf('227');
    if (a > -1)
    {
        var st = d.indexOf("(",a);
        var en = d.indexOf(")",a);
        var str;
        str = d.substring(st + 1,en);
        var a2 = str.split(",");
        var p1 = a2.pop();
        var p2 = a2.pop();
        var ip:String = a2.join(".");
        var port:int=(p2*256)+(p1*1);      
        r.connect(ip, port);
    }
    if(d.indexOf("226 ")>-1){
        text_txt.appendText("QUIT command sent\n");
        s.writeUTFBytes("QUIT \n");
        s.flush();
    }
    if(d.indexOf("221 ")>-1){
    }
}
function onPasvConn(evt:Event):void
{
    //trace("CONNECTED TO DATA PORT");
    text_txt.appendText("CONNECTED TO DATA PORT\n");
    s.writeUTFBytes("NLST "+ftp_path+"\n");
    s.flush();
}
function onServData(evt:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var d = r.readUTFBytes(r.bytesAvailable);
    trace(d);
    text_txt.appendText(d);
}
function onIOERR(evt:IOErrorEvent)
{
    trace(evt.errorID+":"+evt.text);
    text_txt.appendText(evt.errorID+":"+evt.text);
}

function onSecERR(evt){
    text_txt.appendText("Security error\n");
}

function handleGlobalErrors(evt){
    text_txt.appendText("Unhandeled Error\n");
}
```

Comment: try a port over 10000 since the ones under 10000 are reserved ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I fixed the bug.

For some reason the server didn't respond to command with (\n) linebreaks.

I changed it to (\r\n) and it's working fine now

I hope this helps someone

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for posting your solution, I could not get this to work either!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of 3G Carriers block certain ports, which will cause it to fail.

Pretty sure AS3 itself does not act differently on 3G.